# Is it possible to extend an existing object with an interface?

Tags: asp.net, typescript, vue.js

In my Vue-File I am getting a ViewModel object. The ViewModel has the properties FirstName, LastName and Birthdate. It will be returned from the view as JSON. So it should look like -

```
{ FirstName: "Something", LastName: "Anything", Birthdate: 01.01.2001 }
```

Next, I would like to access this JSON-Package in my Vue-File with:

```
model = document.getElementById('app')?.attributes['data'].LastName
```

But is it possible to make kind of a "registration" for the model, so it shows the possibilities for the object -

```
model = document.getElementById('app')?.attributes['data']
```

In this scenario there would be the possibilities to have an autocompletion for LastName, FirstName and Birthdate. I thought of an interface where I could define the properties but that didnt work for me. Hopefully my question is understandable. I am thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can just add an overload that returns an element with a more specific type when you provide the id `"app"`: `declare global { interface Document { getElementById(id: "app"): HTMLElement & { attributes: { data: { LastName: string; } } } } } `

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes this solves the issue, but is there an alternative to do this scoped to a specific file instead of declaring it global ? Thank you anyway :-)

Comment: It has to be a global augmentation because you're retrieving the element using the global DOM API `document.getElementById`. I don't see that as an issue however because IDs are unique within an HTML document. The `declare global` syntax is just a way to add something to the global scope from within a module file which is typical in a Vue app.